# Creating a SelectListItem with the disabled="disabled" attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm not seeing a way to create, via the `HtmlHelper`, a `SelectListItem` that will spit out the following HTML:

```
<option disabled="disabled">don't click this</option>
```

The only properties [`SelectListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.aspx) has are:

```
new SelectListItem{
  Name = "don't click this",
  Value = string.Empty,
  Selected = false
}
```

The only option I see is to

1. Subclass the `SelectListItem` to add an `Enabled` property to get the value to the view
2. Not use the [HTML helper for DropDownList](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=aspnet&changeSetId=23011#288014)
3. Create a new `HtmlHelper` extension that accepts my new `EnablableSelectList` and adds my `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is something I might try before recreating the helper completely.  The basic idea is that the Html you get from the helper should be well formed, so it should be safe to parse.  So you can build on that idea by making your own extension that uses the existing extension but adds the functionality to disable the items.

Something like this might do (totally untested)

```
public class CustomSelectItem : SelectListItem
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyDropDownList(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<CustomSelectItem> selectList)
    {
        var selectDoc = XDocument.Parse(html.DropDownList("", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)selectList).ToString());

        var options = from XElement el in selectDoc.Element("select").Descendants()
                                    select el;

        foreach (var item in options)
        {
            var itemValue = item.Attribute("value");
            if (!selectList.Where(x => x.Value == itemValue.Value).Single().Enabled)
                item.SetAttributeValue("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        // rebuild the control, resetting the options with the ones you modified
        selectDoc.Root.ReplaceNodes(options.ToArray());
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(selectDoc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 That's definitely lighter than recreating the entire helper extension; however, if I was going to recreate it, I would probably just steal the source for the Helper Extension and tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 28):

The `Disabled` property is supported since ASP.NET MVC 5.2:

```
new SelectListItem {
    // ...
    Disabled = true
}
```

See the [API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.disabled.aspx).

Comment: It is also the joke of the century! In short, it has no effect on the retarded helper called `DropdownList`! :)

Comment: @Mrchief you need to use IEnumerable<SelectListItem> for the disabled flag to be respected, and not SelectList. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424365/net-mvc-5-2-3-how-to-create-a-disabled-option-out-of-selectlistitem

Comment: Thanks for the useful info @co7e!

Answer (score 5):

Clientside option: if you for example give your dropdownlist a class 'custom' and the items that should be unselectable the value -1 (for example), then you can do something like:

```
$('select.custom option[value=-1]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is prevent a user from selecting a certain value from the list, it seems like the simpler and more time-efficient way to do it is to use input validation.  Which you may quite possibly be doing anyways, if you want to verify they've made a selection to begin with.

Comment: I already have input validation that invalidates the selection, but all other browsers, besides IE,  will not let you select the item at all if the `disabled="disabled"` attribute is present.

Comment: Going forward IE 8 will support it, or does support it.  For IE 6 and 7 I would agree that you'd have to try and create your own Item, but I'm not certain the best approach there.  Again, I would look at how long it would take to work on that, and see if it's worth the time spent troubleshooting it given what browsers/version users will be using.

Comment: Actually, IE7 does obey the `disabled="disabled"`. I must retract all my disdain for IE....on this issue. I'm just really surprised the `Enabled` attribute was left off the `SelectListItem`.

Answer (score 0):

-----Option 1
Controller:

var ExpectedShipmentsRange = new List();

```
ExpectedShipmentsRange.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Selected number of shipments", Value="0", Disabled = true, Selected  = true });
ExpectedShipmentsRange.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "0 to 20 shipments", Value = "0-20" });
ExpectedShipmentsRange.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "20 to 40 shipments", Value = "20-40" });

ViewBag.ExpectedShipmentsRange = ExpectedShipmentsRange;
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExpectedShipments, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.ExpectedShipmentsRange, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

-----Option 2
Controller:

```
ViewBag.citiesSa = _dbContext.Countries.ToList();
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(@ViewBag.citiesSa, "Id", "Name"), "Select your city", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

-----Option 3 does not support disabled option:

```
List<SelectListItem> ExpectedShipmentsRange = new List<SelectListItem>();
ExpectedShipmentsRange.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "0 to 20 shipments", Value = "0-20" });
ExpectedShipmentsRange.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "20 to 40 shipments", Value = "20-40" });

ViewBag.ExpectedShipmentsRange = new SelectList(ExpectedShipmentsRange, "Value", "Text");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExpectedShipments, (SelectList)@ViewBag.ExpectedShipmentsRange, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that while using `SelectList` to populate the `DropDownListFor()` method the `Disabled` & `Selected` parameters are not respected. They are only honored when populating using `List<SelectListItem>`. However I've run into other odd bugs when populating the `DropDownListFor()` using `List<SelectListItem>` and found that using `SelectList` is the correct option for populating a `DropDownListFor()` list. Here's an example of how to create a `SelectList` list:

```
    public static SelectList States = new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "AL", Value = "AL" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "AK", Value = "AK" },
        ...
    }, "Value", "Text", 1);
```

In my case I needed to `disable` the first item of the select list, the only way I was able to do so using the `SelectList` was by creating an extension method for the `DropDownListFor()` method. Here is the class I used:

```
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        private static MvcHtmlString DisableFirstItemDropDownListFor(MvcHtmlString source, string sourceItemName, string sourceItemValue = "", string targetItemValue = "")
        {
            string htmlString = source.ToHtmlString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceItemValue))
            {
                htmlString = htmlString.Replace("value=\"\"", "value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\" selected=\"selected\"");
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(htmlString);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString DisableFirstItemDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return DisableFirstItemDropDownListFor(htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, htmlAttributes), string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

You can then use this method in your `.cshtml` file like so:

```
@Html.DisableFirstItemDropDownListFor(x => x.YourFieldType, Model.YourModel, new { @class = "YourClass" })
```