# Making my own HtmlHelper extension for input that works with model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

I am unhappy with the current DropDownList implementation, because I can't really do much with the option tags (only selected, text and value is supported). I want to make my own where I can set disabled and other stuff on individual options.

Currently I'm altering the options by javascript, but I think it's a bit of a hacky way to do it, and I'd prefer to just render the correct html to begin with.

I know I can just make a template that uses select and option tags and make the options as I want them - but the normal DropDownList extension adds stuff val stuff and a specific name and ID which I guess is for proper databinding when submitting the form:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedValue must be a number." id="ParentDropDown_SelectedValue" name="ParentDropDown.SelectedValue">
```

How do I go about adding these attributes to my own templates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655035/creating-a-selectlistitem-with-the-disabled-disabled-attribute

Comment: You're right, he's wanting the same end result. I had not found that. But I don't like the answer in there as it seems kinda hacky too. I'm going to give Daniel J. G.'s answer a try as it looks like the way I wanted to go.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are right, those attributes (and specially the name attribute) are critical for the model binding.

Say you want to create a custom helper like

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomHelperFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
```

First you can use `var fieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);` to get the field name.

Then use `var fullBindingName = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(fieldName);` in order to get the full name, taking care of nested views.

Finally you can transform this into an id attribute using `var fieldId = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullBindingName);`.

So a simple custom helper that creates a textbox could be written as:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomHelperFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{            
    var fieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var fullBindingName = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(fieldName);
    var fieldId = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullBindingName);

    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var value = metadata.Model;

    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("input");
    tag.Attributes.Add("name", fullBindingName);
    tag.Attributes.Add("id", fieldId);
    tag.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
    tag.Attributes.Add("value", value == null ? "" : value.ToString());

    var validationAttributes = html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(fullBindingName, metadata);
    foreach (var key in validationAttributes.Keys)
    {
        tag.Attributes.Add(key, validationAttributes[key].ToString());
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

You can use it in a view like:

```
@Html.CustomHelperFor(model => model.ParentDropDown.SelectedValue)
```

And it will produce the following html:

```
<input id="ParentDropDown_SelectedValue" name="ParentDropDown.SelectedValue" type="text" value="4">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! This has helped me a long way. Now I just need to figure out how to databind it to a property of the model. I have a model that represents the whole DropDownList with options and selected value. I generate the html from this, and need to databind the value to the SelectedValue property. I'm guessing I should look into making a name and/or id that fits that property.

Comment: I have updated my answer including a bit of logic that would include data-annotation validation attributes in the rendered html.

Comment: Thanks. I had wondered about that, but I figured I could live without it since there would still be server side validation.

Comment: thanks, this has been a big help. Just wondering why you pass in a Expression. could you pass in the model object though and have the binding still work?

Comment: The expression is mainly required so binding complex objects works as in `model.ParentDropDown.SelectedValue`. This way the generated html can take into account the _ParentDropDown_ prefix and generated `ParentDropDown_SelectedValue` as the input id