# How disable parent items on dropdownlistfor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a `Region` class like this:

```
public class Region
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Name { get; set; }

   public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And `Person` has region:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Name { get; set; }
   public int SurName { get; set; }

   public int RegionId { get; set; }
}
```

But, **it is not like tree node**. There are only 2 floors. Countries and it's sub regions - cities. I use bootstrap template.

I collect this regions like this list:

```
Country1    //need to disable this
    City1
    City2
    City3
Country2    //need to disable this
    City1
    City2
```

In person create action:

```
Viewbag.Regions = new SelectList(MyRepository.LoadRegions(), "Id", "Name");
```

And in view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RegionId, ViewBag.Regions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-", new { data_rel = "chosen", @id = "region" })
```

Finally, I need when dropdown opens, to disable countries, it is possible to select only cities.

How can I disable elements in dropdownlis which `parentId == 0` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a SelectListItem with the disabled="disabled" attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655035/creating-a-selectlistitem-with-the-disabled-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could take is to load up the Regions, remove the Parent items, and then assign the SelectList to the Viewbag.

```
var regions = MyRepository.LoadRegions();
/* remove parent items from regions */
ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(regions, "Id", "Name");
```

**EDIT** I previously misunderstood the question. You want to have headers that aren't selectable. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc) about MVC supporting [OptGroups](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) (which I think will accomplish what you're going for). Turns out the base Html.DropDown helper doesn't support it but you can write a custom one, and in the linked question there is a sample of a custom helper for this case.

Comment: But i want to display, but make disable them

Comment: Ah! I think I understand more your question, I edited with a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks, i have already done my problem. I just used htmlhelpers too. For that idea i accept your answer.