# Earliest opportunity to disable items in SelectListItem rendered with razor DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to disable a couple of items in a dropdown list. Obviously, "Select Country" and a "-----" divider I've inserted. The list is created with `SelectListItem` and rendered with `DropDownListFor` in razor.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655035/creating-a-selectlistitem-with-the-disabled-disabled-attribute) shows one way of doing it, but I'm not sure how to implement that helper. It's also 4 years old and I'm wondering if there isn't a better/easier way at this time. jQuery is an option, but would like to avoid that if possible.

```
$("#Country option[value*='-1']").prop('disabled', true);
```

Is there a better solution yet?

In Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountryList()
{
    var countries = new SelectList(dbLocations.Countries, "Country", "CountryName").ToList();
    countries.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Country", Value = "-1" }));
    countries.Insert(1, (new SelectListItem { Text = "United Sates", Value = "USA" }));
    countries.Insert(2, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Canada", Value = "CAN" }));
    countries.Insert(3, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Mexico", Value = "MEX" }));
    countries.Insert(4, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Brazil", Value = "BRA" }));
    countries.Insert(5, (new SelectListItem { Text = "-----------", Value = "-1" }));

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> countrylist =
        countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.Text,
            Value = m.Value
        });

    return countrylist;
}
```

In View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.CountryCode,
new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text"), 
new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<select name="Country" id="Country">
    <option value="-1">Select Country</option>
    <option value="USA" selected="selected">United Sates</option>
    <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
    <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="BRA">Brazil</option>
    <option value="-1">------------------------</option>
    <option value="ABW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AIA">Anguilla</option>

    ...

</select>
```

Comment: What determines if the field should be disabled?

Comment: Justin, I edited my question and added a line of jQuery that will disable all items with a `value="-1"`. I suppose that's not such a bad option, but I was hoping there was a way of disabling a SelectListItem in the C# code when the list is created.