# .Net MVC 5.2.3: how to create a disabled option out of SelectListItem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a dropdown  list with a few options disabled so that they are not selectable. Here is my code:

```
var places = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Virgin Islands", Value = "Virgin Islands"},
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "", Value = "", Disabled= true},
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Canada", Value = "Canada", Disabled= true},
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "", Value = "", Disabled= true},
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Other", Value = "Other"},
}, "Value", "Text");
```

However, generated HTML for the disabled SelectListItem is merely:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

How can I generate the following HTML

```
<option disabled="disabled"></option>
```

from SelectListItem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Disabled` property will only be respected if you use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `SelectList` (in the `SelectList` contructor, you are only setting the properties of `Value` and `Text`) and in any case there is little point creating `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` then creating `SelectList` from it when the helper only accepts `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
var places = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Virgin Islands", Value = "Virgin Islands"},
    new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "", Value = "", Disabled= true},
    ....
};
```

then in the helper

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.YourProperty, model.places) // or (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.places
```

Side note: `SelectList` does have an overloaded constructor that takes `IEnumerable disabledValues` as a parameter ([refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749647(v=vs.118).aspx))

Comment: Stephen, I used "var places = new List<SelectListItem>" as you suggested. Then I used DropDownListFor as in: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Place, places, new { @class = "form-control" }). I got compilation error with DropDownList.

Comment: The second parameter does not look right - it would need to be `Model.places` (if places is a property of your model) or `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.places` if your assigning the select list to a `ViewBag` property

Answer (score 2):

You are not taking into account `Disabled` property of `SelectListItem`, so -

Return your model as typeof

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

instead of

```
SelectList
```

And just bind as -

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Prop, model.places);
```

Hope this helps.